# Searching algorithm for mine detector

Tags: algorithm, search, arduino, robot

Basically I need to find an algorithm that will search a circular area for multiple mines minimising looking in the same place twice. The robot can start anywhere on the edge of the circle. I've looked into things like A* but all of them require knowledge of each goal before hand. The whole point of a mine detection robot is that the goals are unknown.Any cheap sensors can be used.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can the robot detect mines which are 1,2... fields away or only the ones directly under him? Is the goal to minimize search time?

Comment: Only mines directly in front of it, and yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just run a spiral?
it is not optimized at 100%, as te external circle will overlap a bit at the end, but it is the best for easy to write/debug (even visually).

For sensor it all depends on with kind of mine you are loking for. There are a lot of trick, like "minimum metal mine" (no metal detector will work on them) and so on.

Comment: Thank you I think I'll just do this. Looks a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the `Ant Colony Optimization` algorithm for this task, although I'm not agree with you about *"all of them require knowledge of each goal before hand"*, cause you can use as much as domain knowledge that is provided for you.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms) is a good place to start getting some information about the ACO (if required).

The reason that I suggest you ACO is it's intrinsic analogy with the problem you got.

---

If you provide more details about the problem I can tell you more about how to apply ACO to solve it (if required).